# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ID"

Tags: java, graphics, interface

I'm trying to make a program that asks for an ID. it stores the ID and if you want to search  it, you type the ID and click "Search". The program will show information of the ID. (Name, Adress, Phone number, etc). The problem is that when i click "Search" it gives me this error(shown at title). I may have forgotten some information, if so please tell me. Im new to this website and Java and i couldn't find anything on google that would FIX it.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "ID"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:492)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
```

Code

```
 ...ArrayList<Trabajador> listaTrabajadores = new ArrayList<Trabajador>();
```

.

```
    ...private void bt_BuscarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    String idStr = lb_ID.getText();
    if("".equals(idStr)) {
        mostrarMensaje("Please enter an ID.");
        return;
    }
    try {
        int id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
        for (Trabajador trabajador : listaTrabajadores) {
            if(trabajador.getId() == id){
              jt_Nombre.setText(trabajador.getNombre());
              jt_Direccion.setText(trabajador.getDireccion());
              jt_Telefono.setText(trabajador.getTelefono());
              jt_Sueldo.setText(String.valueOf(trabajador.getSueldo()));

              ComboBoxModel cbm = this.cb_Region.getModel();
                for (int i = 0; i < cbm.getSize(); i++) {
                    if(cbm.getElementAt(i).toString().equals(trabajador.getRegion())) {
                        cbm.setSelectedItem(i);
                        return;
                    }

                }
            } 
        }
          mostrarMensaje("ID not found");
      } catch (Exception e) {
        mostrarMensaje("ID has to be numeric");
    }

}
```

"Trabajador" Class

```
public class Trabajador {
private int id;
private String nombre;
private String direccion;
private String telefono;
private int sueldo;
private String region;

public Trabajador() {
}

public Trabajador(int id, String nombre, String direccion, String telefono, int sueldo, String region) {
    this.id = id;
    this.nombre = nombre;
    this.direccion = direccion;
    this.telefono = telefono;
    this.sueldo = sueldo;
    this.region = region;
}



public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}

public String getDireccion() {
    return direccion;
}

public void setDireccion(String direccion) {
    this.direccion = direccion;
}

public String getTelefono() {
    return telefono;
}

public void setTelefono(String telefono) {
    this.telefono = telefono;
}

public int getSueldo() {
    return sueldo;
}

public void setSueldo(int sueldo) {
    this.sueldo = sueldo;
}

public String getRegion() {
    return region;
}

public void setRegion(String region) {
    this.region = region;
}
```

}

Comment: public int getSueldo() {
        return sueldo;
    }

Comment: are you sure `idStr` is an integer? Not for example "ID: 2" ?

Comment: Found the problem, it was **lb_ID**. Changed it to **jt_ID**, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that i was using the wrong object. I was using **lb_ID** instead of **jt_ID** at **String idStr = lb_ID.getText();**.